# Horizontal line on ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a horizontal line to be placed over my ggplot2 bar plot at the average of all the bars:

```
ggplot(bar_graph, aes(x=V1, y=numBridges)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  xlab("Agreement")+
  ylab("Number of Nodes")+
  geom_hline(yintercept=15)
```

Unfortunately this code gives me the error message:

```
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Which is super odd because `15` is not a list. It's also even more odd because, just to check, I ran the following code to make a vertical line - which worked well:

```
ggplot(bar_graph, aes(x=V1, y=numBridges)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  xlab("Agreement")+
  ylab("Number of Bridge Nodes")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=5)
```

A couple years ago there was a bug in ggplot2 that could only be resolved by installing directly from github, so in the event that this was still the problem I ran:

```
remove.packages('ggplot2')
devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')
```

But that did not work either.

On Mac Monterrey:

```
packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.3.6.9000’
```

Does anyone have any ideas or workarounds? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: The error indicates that one of the columns in `bar_graph` (probably `numBridges`) is a list. What does `str(bar_graph)` show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to neilfws for pointing out that the column in my dataframe was indeed a list. I just did `bar_graph$numBridges %>% unlist()` to fix it.

I guess a nice reminder that a dataframe can be a cleverly hidden list!